# Does MySQL rotates the log in place?

Tags: mysql, logrotate

Does MySQL rotates the log in place?
How does mysql rotates logs internally. I tried searching for script which mysql use to rotate logs but could not find it.
How are the parameters like expire_logs_days used by mysql?

Answer (score 0):

`expire_logs_days` refers to the *binary* logs, which are the transaction logs and as their name implies, not human-readable.  The logs meant for human consumption are not rotated automatically.  Most distributions manage these logs using `logrotate` which generally does not operate "in-place" (though it can be configured to do so).